# C++, Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, memory

### Debug Assertion Failed

I spend a lot of time trying to fond out why I have an assert in this code.

If there is no string in the class, it's work well.

Can you explaine,
 why I have an Assert whit the class containing string.

Thank's
Marc

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string>

class CTheClassWith_string
{
private:
    std::string TheName_;
};

class CTheClassWith_int
{
private:
    int TheName_;
};

int main()
{
std::string theString;
int size;

CTheClassWith_int   TheClassWith_int;
CTheClassWith_string TheClassWith_string;

CTheClassWith_int* pTheClassWith_int = new CTheClassWith_int;
size = _msize(pTheClassWith_int);
delete pTheClassWith_int;

CTheClassWith_string* pTheClassWith_string = new CTheClassWith_string;
size = _msize(pTheClassWith_string);
delete pTheClassWith_string;

CTheClassWith_int* pArrayTheClassWith_int = new CTheClassWith_int[2];
size = _msize(pArrayTheClassWith_int);
delete [] pArrayTheClassWith_int;

CTheClassWith_string* pArrayTheClassWith_string = new CTheClassWith_string[2];
size = _msize(pArrayTheClassWith_string);             // Why I assert on this line
delete [] pArrayTheClassWith_string;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say, what is `_msize`? It's not a standard function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So says [ideone](http://ideone.com/09IV5J). It doesn't even compile.

Comment: The _msize function returns the size, in bytes, of the memory block allocated by a call to calloc, malloc, or realloc.

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010. same thing with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Comment: @user3361911 `new` and `delete` aren't the same things as `malloc()`, `free()` et al., you can't rely that `new[]()` should call one of the `malloc()` family functions underneath!

Comment: @user3361911 - Yes, your class contains a std::string. However what caused you to now start writing code using new[] and malloc? If you want to know how many items you allocated, either save that number somewhere, or use a container such as std::vector (then you use the size() function).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie _'writing code using new[] and malloc? ...'_ The OP actually doesn't use `malloc()`.

Comment: If you want dynamic arrays, and need to know the number of elements in them, there's always [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As I understood the OP want's a way to determine the overall size allocated from the heap with the `new` calls.

Comment: No, sorry, but I dont want to know the number of element in the array. I Just want to know why there an Assert when there is a string in the class.   With Visual C++, the "new" call the "malloc" function.

Comment: @user3361911 Note that `std::string` does it's dynamic memory management internally. I can't tell what's the particular reason for the assertion, maybe elaborate on the assertion text, or check where the stack trace comes from. If you want to be specific for `_msize()`, tag the question [tag:visual-c++] or such ...

Comment: @UnBinBonGars `new` may *call* `malloc`, but it's very unlikely that the pointer it returns alway  is the one that `malloc` returned. Especially `new[]`, which needs more bookkeeping for destruction, and possibly other things.

Answer (score 0):

As from your question I understood you want to determine the size in bytes allocated from heap, when using `new()` or `new[]()`.

Well, you cannot use the `_msize()` function to achieve this. Besides it's a legacy function, the pointers obtained with `new` aren't necessarily coming from underlying calls to functions from the `malloc()` family (which `_msize()` relies on in turn, thus the assertion).

To determine sizes allocated from the heap (or elsewhere), you can always rely on the `sizeof()` operator:

```
CTheClassWith_int* pTheClassWith_int = new CTheClassWith_int;
size = sizeof(CTheClassWith_int);
delete pTheClassWith_int;

CTheClassWith_string* pTheClassWith_string = new CTheClassWith_string;
size = sizeof(CTheClassWith_string);
delete pTheClassWith_string;

CTheClassWith_int* pArrayTheClassWith_int = new CTheClassWith_int[2];
size = sizeof(CTheClassWith_int) * 2;
delete [] pArrayTheClassWith_int;

CTheClassWith_string* pArrayTheClassWith_string = new CTheClassWith_string[2];
size = sizeof(CTheClassWith_string) * 2;
delete [] pArrayTheClassWith_string;
```

Comment: I just want to know why there is an Assert. Under Visual C++, in debug mode, the "new" function is in the "new.cpp" file.  And the "new" make call to malloc().

Comment: @user3361911 OK, I just said, you can't **rely** on this. Your problem seems to be specific for the `_msize()` though! Please retag your question as I've been asking for.